# VBA binary file - cnc program

Tags: excel, vba, text-files, createobject, cnc

I'm using a macro to create a CNC program.
To create the ".spf" file the machine is using I use:

```
Dim m2_path as string
m2_path = T:\Production\Cavity-Line\Eric R\Excel\PARAMETER.spf

Dim text as string
text = 'my data

Dim fso As Object
Dim Fileout As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile(m2_path, True, True)
Fileout.Write text
Fileout.Close
```

When I try to open the program on the machine I get a error "Cannot open binary files".
But If I manually copy the content from the "m2_path"-file into another one and then try to open it, I don't get the error message.

Is there something wrong with the formatting of the text file?

Machine is using SINUMERIK 840d sl.

Thanks in advance
Regards

**EDIT:**
Thanks to [@ashleedawg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8112776/ashleedawg%22@ashleedawg)

Comment: The first thing that's missing is double quotes around the path.  And, I gather the machine is expect a text file?

Comment: Fixed that. Yes, with the ending .spf. (file format)

Comment: Did that fix the problem?  If not, are you able to post a sample file generated by your code?

Comment: Have you seen page 29 of [this document](https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/881/49913881/att_62227/v1/siemense_operate_26_sp1_hf4.pdf)?

Comment: This helped me, thanks!

Comment: `Is there something wrong with the formatting of the text file?` the answer is yes. but it is impossible to say what that is. you did not post enough information. .... can you post the first few likes fro a working spf file and a few lines fro your spf file?

Comment: did you get it figured out?

Comment: Please either you or @ashleedawg, post the answer as an answer and remove it from the question. Is it depending on writing the text with an ANSI encoding when UTF-8 is required (which does work for characters in the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block only)?

Comment: @Tom -- _done_.

Comment: @rosi97 -- if that's working for you now, feel free to "accept" my answer (with the checkmark below on the left), which I moved from your Edit as per Tom's request.  Good luck with the CNC!  (Coincidentally, my uncle worked on the first PLC's & CNC's for Siemens in Berlin about 50 years ago.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good to hear you had success with the change:

> From :
>
> ```
> Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile(m2_path, True, True)
> ```
>
> to :
>
> ```
> Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile(m2_path, True, False)
> ```
>
> to create a ASCII file instead of Unicode (which could not be read by
>   the machine).

<sub>**Reference**: [Siemens SINUMERIK 840D sl CNC Software 2.6 SP1 HF4 Installation/Operating Manual, Page 29](https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/881/49913881/att_62227/v1/siemense_operate_26_sp1_hf4.pdf)</sub>

> Text files can be edited using the SINUMERIK Operate Editor if the
>   text files use the LF character (0aH) or the character string CRLF
>   (0d0aH) as line or end of block identifier. The editor cannot open
>   binary files.  ...  Files that are newly generated from the SINUMERIK
>   Operate Editor are UTF-8-coded - and have the LF characters as end of
>   block identifier. For UTF-8-coded files, all special characters are
>   correctly displayed. When opening files, the SINUMERIK Operate Editor
>   assumes that the files are UTF-8-coded. If files with another coding
>   are opened, e.g. with Windows page coding, then the special characters
>   are only correctly displayed if the SINUMERIK Operate was changed over
>   to the appropriate system language. This also involves e.g. files that
>   were generated using the HMI-Advanced Editor. When opening with the
>   SINUMERIK Operate Editor, the coding of such files is not changed.
>   There is no automatic conversion into UTF-8-coding. If files we re
>   generated or processed with an external editor (e.g. Notepad under
>   Windows) and not the SINUMERIK Operate Editor, then it should be noted
>   that the file is saved, UTF-8-coded. When using Notepad, and when
>   saving the file as encoding select "UTF-8" in the “Save As” dialog
>   box. If special characters are not being used, then "ANSI" can also be
>   specified as encoding.